# Errors with "git push heroic master", what to do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

So i'm trying to deploy my rails app through heroku. But every time i run "git push heroic master", i run into this. I have searched around, but nothing seems to work. I have tried to "bundle update", "bundle install", but i still get this error when i run "git push heroic master"

```
Counting objects: 84, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (70/70), done.
Writing objects: 100% (84/84), 20.65 KiB | 1.88 MiB/s, done.
Total 84 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote:  !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
remote:             Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
remote:             See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.1). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
remote:        your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
remote:        updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
remote:        The dependencies in your gemfile changed
remote:        You have added to the Gemfile:
remote:        * pg
remote:        Bundler Output: Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.1). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
remote:        your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
remote:        updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
remote:        
remote:        The dependencies in your gemfile changed
remote:        
remote:        You have added to the Gemfile:
remote:        * pg
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to secret-mesa-55611.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/******
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/*******.git'
```

Comment: As the error notes, are you checking in the new Gemfile.lock?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your Gemfile.lock is changed. Try running `bundle install` after cleaning the Gemfile.lock

Comment: What do you mean by "cleaning" the gemfile.lock?

Comment: I mean delete everything from Gemfile.lock and again bundle install.